# Unwanted Blurriness using GWT with html5 Canvas

Tags: java, html, gwt, canvas

I have an issue with html5 canvas. The lines I like to draw look blurry. For example I am painting a rectangle (just horizontal and vertical lines) with a line width of 1 and the line is at least 2px or 3px thick...
Especially when painting text, it is barley readable, because of the thickness and blurriness.

Zoomed in example picture. The line-width is set to 1

[image: Zoomed in example. The line-width is set to 1]

I am using: GWT and therefore have to paint the canvas object using Java.

I tried:

- the Context2d's "translate(0.5, 0.5)"-method
- as you see, the width and height are set as an attribute of the canvas element
- different browsers

The html element looks like this:

```
<canvas width="200" height="100" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></canvas>
```

Painting a rectangle i.e. looks like this:

```
//Initializing
m_canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
m_canvas.getCanvasElement().setWidth(200);
m_canvas.getCanvasElement().setHeight(100);
m_context = m_canvas.getContext2d();

//Painting filled the rectangle
m_context.beginPath();    
m_context.setLineWidth(1);
m_context.setStrokeStyle("#000000");
m_context.setFillStyle("#BBBBBB");   
m_context.rect(1, 1, 198, 23);   
m_context.fill();
m_context.stroke();
```

I need some help to make this blurring disappear please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I solved it by putting -0.5 everywhere I draw:

```
context2d.fillRect( left - 0.5, top - 0.5, width, height );
```

It's really annoying.